# Word for wandering in a scared, aimless manner?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who wanders, but not in the pleasant meandering type of way. Instead in an aimless, broken, scared kind of way, like a child wandering ruins.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

That is still *meandering*.

***[Meander](https://www.yourdictionary.com/meander)*** means *to take a winding course or wander aimlessly.*

Or ***[bumble](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bumble)*** if you move in an awkward or confused manner.

***[Trail](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trail)*** is also possible, it means *to move slowly and without energy or enthusiasm.*

***[Lumber](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lumber)*** and ***[plod](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plod)*** would also work.

Answer (score 1):

The only verb I can think of that involves walking and fear is [**slink**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slink):

> **1** : to go or move stealthily or furtively (as in fear or shame) : [STEAL](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steal)

However, that doesn't necessarily mean an aimless walk. In fact, I can't think of anything that would combine both aimless and fearful, because when you're afraid, and without another purpose, you tend to walk quickly to get out of the area you're afraid of.

In short, if you are afraid you almost always *have* an aim: either to escape or to quickly finish whatever needs to be done and then escape.

Answer (score 0):

> [*furtive*](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/furtive) - attempting to avoid notice or attention, typically because of guilt or a belief that discovery would lead to trouble; secretive.

or, more aimless, less fearful, but specifically wandering...

> [*peripatetic*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiM96_j54rrAhUdgnIEHXx9Cg0QFjACegQIERAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.collinsdictionary.com%2Fus%2Fdictionary%2Fenglish%2Fperipatetic&usg=AOvVaw2rEHLyHQxVLr4VXw5Pqbhe) - If someone has a peripatetic life or career, they travel around a lot, living or working in places for short periods of time.